# How to correctly synchronize the internal state of the input field with the React Hook Form value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using the MUI component library with RHF.

For quick form creation, I want to create my collection of form fields to be controlled by RHF.

But I'm facing a problem synchronizing the internal state of some complex fields, like DatePicker, with the state of the form.

For simple input components like TextField I don't create an additional internal state because I don't need to transform the value entered by the user before sending it to the form.

However, components like the DatePicker work with complex objects like the Moment object. I want to get a formatted value like "2022-02-02" after submitting the form, so I create an internal state that contains the Moment value and call RHF onChange with the formatted value I want.

```
const [momentValue, setMomentValue] = useState(() => getMomentDateTime(value));

const handleChange = useCallback(
    (newValue) => {
        setMomentValue(newValue);
        onChange(
            newValue && newValue.isValid()
                ? newValue.format(format)
                : '',
        );
    },
    [format, onChange],
);
```

This approach works fine until the external action is on the field.

For example, I have two date input fields at the level above. When I change the first one, I should automatically set the second one to "date of the first field + 1 day". To do this, I use setValue. This method will update the form's value but not the internal state's value. Therefore, the UI will not be updated.

I have to use useEffect, keep track of the form value change, compare it to the internal value, and update as needed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (value !== momentValue.format(format)) {
        setMomentValue(getMomentDateTime(value));
    }
}, [format, momentValue, value]);
```

I wouldn't say I like this approach. A similar check for MultipleSelect looks even more complicated.

How can this problem be solved correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your question, as I'm struggling with a related problem (I believe): my RHF form has its state modified in a way that must be dealt with procedurally, using `setValue` calls. However since those calls are asynchronous, I have trouble when they are performed in a certain order. It seems to me that having a `setValues` call, thus being able to update multiple form values at once, would solve the issue, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also using RHF with MUI. RHF has method to integrate with UI library using **Controller**. See https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries

I already used it with TextField, Radio, DatePicker, etc and works fine. Sample code would be like this:

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required: true,
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
      <TextInput
        placeholder="First name"
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onChangeText={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
    )}
    name="firstName"
  />
```